# Why external js is not loading while using ip address but working while using localhost?

Tags: javascript, jquery, localhost

I moved my JQuery code from JSP to external JS file. I've imported the JS correctly. It's working fine while using localhost:8080/... but worst part is it's failing when I replace localhost to 10.100.30.100 (ipv4 of my machine). Why is it happening?

Comment: it sounds like a firewall issue. Is your local machine's 8080 port open to allow remote connection? turn off all firewalls and then try again.

Comment: What webserver are you using? You might be listening to port 8080 but binded to IP 127.0.0.1 only...